# c# How to convert int array to string binary array

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to convert numbers in an array `znaky` to array in binary numbers called `binary`, but it returns me error.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
char[] znaky = new char[moje.Length];                                                                                                                                                                 
for (int i = 0; i < znaky.Length; i++)
{                                                                                          
    znaky[i] = moje[i];                                                                         
}

string binary = "";
foreach (int a in znaky)
{
    binary += Convert.ToString(znaky[a], 2);  
}
```

In array `moje` was the numbers, but for me I change his positions. In this program I change words to binary code.

Comment: As a suggestion, next time use english names for variables when asking on SO

Comment: And the second `foreach` should be a `for`: `for (int a = 0; a < znaky.Length; a++)`

Comment: Or just use `a` directly instead of `znaky[a]`. But wait, `znaky` is a char array? Does it need to be?

Comment: Can you show us the code before this?  What is `moje` and how is it populated?  Is `moje` a `char[]`?  In which case why are you copying it to `znaky`?

Answer (score 3):

Second `foreach` should be a `for`:

```
for (int a = 0; a < znaky.Length; a++)
```

OR keep the `foreach` and then change the `Convert`:

```
Convert.ToString(a, 2);
```